# How to select range cell with VBA and align to top instead to the middle of the window?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I created a hiperlink, but this is not working correctly. When the vba is executed, always the selected cell is in the middle of the window, i want to align the selected cell to the top left in window with any resolution. This for navigation on the document. My excel is 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code after you make the cell into a hyperlink:

```
Application.Goto Cells(1,1),TRUE
```

Replace `Cells(1,1)` with the appropriate cell.